# How do I fix Age of Empires  color problem?

Tags: games, colors

I have followed [the tutorial here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=147) and I got everything to work but the graphics. Below is what it looks like when I play the William Wallace campaign. I need help. I really want to play the game without these wrong colors, my ubuntu version is 11.10.

[image]

Comment: On that same page you linked to someone (Vndecid) had a similar issue. They said: "Open regedit HKEY_current_user->Software->wine->Direct3D and change Directdrawrender that have the opengl value for gdi"

Comment: Fire up a terminal, and use the following command: `wine regedit`, then navigate through to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Wine -> Direct3D and there should a key called Directdrawrender. Tell me what that is, then I may be able to decipher the rest of what to do. He/she did write it kind of weird...

Comment: What is the value for pixelshadermode when you click on it?

Comment: reverendj1 the pixelshadermode's value data says it is enabled. here is a snapshot i took with my vaio: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4430/screenshotat20120817122.png  please reply when you can.

Comment: i found something else: it is called "vertexshadermode" the value type is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated wine to 1.5.5 and this seems to have fixed the problem.